# Extra parameters in jquery autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am new to asp.net and Jquery. I have some difficulties passing and using additional parameters to the code; I am trying to pass TxtSiteName and txtAccount  to code to use them as parameters in my stored prodcedure;

```html
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtAccount").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "RequisitionService.asmx/GetAccount",
                        data: {
                            term: request.term,
                            Site: $("#txtSiteName").val(),
                            Account: $("txtAccount").val()
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);

                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 0
            });
        });
   </script>
```

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<string> GetAccount(String Site, String Account)
    {
        String CS = "data source = ****; database= ****; user id = ****; Password=****";
        List<string> Accounts = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAccount", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@site",Site);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Accounts.Add(rdr["GLAccountDesc"].ToString());
            }
        }

        return Accounts;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I noticed one typo: `$("txtAccount")` is not a valid selector and should be `$("#txtAccount")`. Still looking over the rest.

Comment: If I understand the logic here, you're passing a `site` and `account` to your .net script, which then passes it to a function. That function uses `site` in the SQL query and appends results to new list, `accounts` that is returned? When is `account` used?

Comment: i just realised i did not use accounts in the function, but I would like to select when the criteria matches both account and site.

Comment: It looks like your stored procedure only accepts one parameter, is that what I see? If you want to return results based on either, your c# will need to do that. I suspect run a second SQL with the `account`, and append to `accounts` lists before returning it. Why not have an autocomplete for each?